# Generic term for spatial data

Tags: terminology

I'm building an application that can accept a shapefile/mapinfo/feature class/spatialite table/etc.  So - various formats from various vendors/organizations.

So let's say the user is going through a wizard to import data (or visualizing that data in plan view)...is there generic term for spatial data?  Something that a typical user would understand that would differentiate it from a text file or standard table?  This isn't a GIS product - it just makes use of GIS data.  It is not limited to use in one area of the world.

Anyone have any experience with lowest common denominator terminology for beginner/intermediate users (advanced users would just figure it out I suppose)?  What is most obvious?

  Spatial data?

  Spatial file?

  Geospatial data/file?

  Geographic data/file/table?

  Data with one weird column/file that I can't understand?

Comment: Sorry all - this is a dup
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34733/spatial-data-geodata-geographic-data-geospatial-data